# ُIs the exponential term necessary in logsoftmax when having positive inputs?

Tags: optimization, logarithms, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Considering the logsoftmax function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ as:
$$[f(x)]_i =-\log\left(\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_j{e^{x_j}}}\right)\quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$
where $x > 0 $ and is the decision vector which needs to be optimized to have more confidence in $i$-th decision as the $i$-th element of $x$. So one can add/use $f(x,i)$ in an optimization setting. Also assume $i$ is fixed.

But also if we define $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$[g(x)]_i =-\log\left(\frac{{x_i}}{\sum_j{{x_j}}}\right) \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$
it has its minimum where $x_i$ is higher than other elements in $x$.

So considering we maintain the solution set as $x > 0$, then what would be the benefit of using $f(x,i)$ over $g(x,i)$?

Does it provide better convexity terms in an optimization setting or any other relevant benefit?

Comment: Is your second function $g(x)$ convex?

Comment: Your functions are ill posed. $f(x_i)$ is a scalar function of a single variable ($x_i$), but you have all of the values of $x$ in the denominator. Please clarify the exact functions you are considering, presumably they are multivariate.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Although i think the definition of the functions are clear enough, i changed the LHS of the equation so you feel better about it. Generally it gives a sense of how big is $x_i$ with respect to other entries of vector $x$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Assuming $i$ is fixed, i think $g(x,i)$ is convex in the same way if $f(x,i)$ can be assumed convex. But i would be happy if you can give a better opinion on that.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Generally i think they are similar, at least i haven't heard any comment or answer yet contradicting that idea.However i think $f(x,i)$ can cause faster convergence to an optimum point comparing to $g$

Comment: I see what you mean but your notation is still not correct. I will edit it. But you cannot _assume_ either function is convex. If you haven't proven $g$ is convex, say with a Hessian test, you may not assume it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thank you. But isn't the logsoftmax itself convex? i mean $[f(x)]_i$, as it is a typical function to use in the last layer of some types of Artificial Neural Networks and is used in the Back Propagation in the chain of derivatives.

Comment: I know the function $h(x)=\log(\sum_i x_i)$ is convex. That's not what you have here. I don't know for sure about $f$, and I certainly don't know it about $g$.

Comment: OK, I need to back up a bit. There's a bit of a disagreement in the use of "softmax" between the optimization folks and the deep learning folks. Optimization folks often call $h(x)$ above to be "softmax". But what deep learning folks call softmax is the _gradient_ of $h(x)$ (see Proposition 1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00805.pdf)). But that is _not_ $f(x)$ above; softmax doesn't have a logarithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71657/discussion-between-bob-and-michael-grant).

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (A) $g(x)$ may go wrong if some $x_i$ are negative and will go wrong if $\sum x_i = 0$; (B) $g(kx)=g(x)$ but typically $f(kx)\not = c f(x)$ so using $f(x)$ might only make sense if $x$ were dimensionless

Comment: @Henry : (A)  won't happen by the definition of the problem.